# Microsoft Enterprise Library not recognize in Azure DevOps

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-devops

I have a web app and it uses `asp.net mvc` and data access using `Enterprise Library`. Project is working fine. But i have setup `VSTS DevOps`. Then it build that and show the error

> > Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

[image]

### MyCode

```
using NewsHub.Domain;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace NewsHub.Data
{
    public class FeedbackRepository : IFeedbackRepository
    {
        Database db;
        DbCommand cmd;
        DbCommand cxd;
        DbConnection con;
        DbTransaction transaction;

        public FeedbackRepository()
        {
            DatabaseProviderFactory factory = new DatabaseProviderFactory();
            db = factory.Create("NewsHubConString");
            con = db.CreateConnection();
        }

        public List<FeedbackDTO> GetAllFeedbacks()
        {
            List<FeedbackDTO> _feedback = new List<FeedbackDTO>();
            try
            {
                con.Open();    
                // Some code goes here    
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {    
                throw;
            }

            return _feedback;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't fix your issue, but that library is no longer under development. I would avoid it. What do you need it for?

Comment: Can you check in nuget restore logs if the dll's been downloaded?

Comment: @WilliamXifaras I have connect my db using Enerprise library.So how to avoid it ?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk where's that logs ?

Comment: In the build summary

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk  oops! it's not there here is that https://pastebin.com/fuAfYhrN

Comment: @TechGuy Can you share your `package.config` file?

Answer (score 0):

> Microsoft Enterprise Library not recognize in Azure DevOps

According to the nuget restore log you provided in your comment:

```
Restoring NuGet package bootstrap.3.0.0.
Restoring NuGet package Antlr.3.4.1.9004.
Restoring NuGet package jQuery.1.10.2.
Restoring NuGet package AutoMapper.8.0.0.
Restoring NuGet package jQuery.Validation.1.11.1.
Restoring NuGet package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.2.2.0.
Restoring NuGet package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept.2.0.6.
Restoring NuGet package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.2.2.0.
Restoring NuGet package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector.2.2.0.
Restoring NuGet package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.2.2.0.
Restoring NuGet package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.2.2.0.
Restoring NuGet package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.2.2.0.
Restoring NuGet package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.3.
Restoring NuGet package Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.3.2.3.
Restoring NuGet package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.1.1.3.
Restoring NuGet package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.5.2.3.
```

We could to know there is no any nuget package about package `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary`, like package `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.dll` in nuget restore list.

So, first, please check your `package.config` file if it include any nuget package about `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary`.

Then make sure you can build successfully on your local, then nsure that the local code is synchronized with the code on the server.

Hope this helps.